# Can't get jQuery raty plugin to work with rails + Backbone.js app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, raty

I'm using the Jquery raty plugin from http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty.
I have a Rails + Backbone.js reviews app, and whenever I add the review form view, I can't get any stars to "turn on" whenever I hover over them. The plug-in works for the read-only ratings, but not for adding ratings
Here's my code for the form sub-view:
//reviews_form.js

```
App.Views.ReviewsForm = Backbone.CompositeView.extend({

    initialize: function(options){
        this.business = options.business;
    },

    template: JST['reviews/form'],
    events: {
        "click #review-submit":"submitForm"
    },
    render: function(){
      var renderedContent = this.template()
      this.$el.html(renderedContent);
      $inputRating = this.$el.find('#input-rating');
        $inputRating.raty();
      return this;
    },

    submitForm: function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.model.reviews().create({
            rating: $('#input-rating').val(), 
            content: this.$(".review_content").val(), 
            business_id: this.business.id
        }, { wait: true });
        $(".review_content").empty(); 
    }
})
```

And I add the reviews form view in the business_show.js file through this code:

```
addReviewForm: function(review){
        var reviewsForm = new Expecto.Views.ReviewsForm({model: this.model, business: this.model});
        this.addSubview(".reviews-form", reviewsForm)
    },
```

My form template is as follows:

```
<h3 class="user-reviews">Add a review</h3>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="new-review-form">
 <div class="form-group">


    <div id="input-rating"></div>
    <label>Review</label><br>
    <textarea name="review[content]" class="review_content" style="width: 500px; height: 150px;"></textarea><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="review[business_id]" value="<%= this.business_id %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="review[user]" value="<%= this.user %>">
    <button id="review-submit" class=" btn btn-primary">Submit</review>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean to say you have got multiple rating controls on your page - after you create or add ratings ?

Comment: yes, I use the plugin(using the read-only attribute) to show the rating of the business, and each of the business reviews, on the same business show page. Is that creating a conflict?

Comment: Hmm, first of all I would suggest that if you have multiple div(s) with the same id `input-rating`, then you must use a class instead, because whatever you have in DOM after it creates multiple reviews - it is not advised to have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: well, I have different classes for each type of rating on each subview. So, the id input rating is used for the review form view only, the business show page ratingdiv has a different id( since there is only one), and the review show view has a class "review-rating". So none of them have the same id.

Comment: Cool, then after the new div has been inserted, do you invoke `$newDiv.raty();` on it ? (`$newDiv` is a jQuery object which represents the newly created div)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you actually have to pass in a callback that raty will use onClick. 
From the raty docs.

```
$('div').raty({
  click: function(score, evt) {
  alert('ID: ' + this.id + "\nscore: " + score + "\nevent: " + evt);
  }
});
```

So in your case just put a function that set's the value of a rating to score `this.val(score)` .